# Can't get auth information from Linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I'm working on authentication with LinkedIn. I don't know why but LinkedIn don't allow to sign in with suddenly. I can allow LinkedIn app but I can't get authentication information.

```
{"provider"=>"linkedin",
"uid"=>nil,
"info"=>
  {"name"=>nil,
  "email"=>nil,
  "nickname"=>nil,
  "first_name"=>nil,
  "last_name"=>nil,
  "location"=>nil,
  "description"=>nil,
  "image"=>nil,
  "phone"=>nil,
  "headline"=>nil,
  "industry"=>nil,
  "urls"=>{"public_profile"=>nil}},
"credentials"=>{"token"=>"facdxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx", "secret"=>"2xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"}}
```

*omniauth_controller.rb*

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def linkedin
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra"))

        if @user.persisted?
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
        else
            session["devise.user_attributes"] = @user.attributes
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

Should I update LinkedIn application settings? I wonder it doesn't matter to the rails application...

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
```

I use `omniauth-linkedin`.

When I register in February, I have permission like below.

[image]

But currently, Just three.

[image]

How can I add permissions on LinkedIn?

Comment: Are you using a omniauth/linkedin gem to enable omniauth in devise?? If so, which one?

Comment: Thanks @JayDorsey I have added gemfile info.

Comment: It looks like [this gem](https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin) which hasn't been updated in 4+ years. The README states "This gem contains the LinkedIn strategy for OmniAuth 1.0" but the link on the microsoft site states "The LinkedIn API uses OAuth 2.0 for user authorization and API authentication." I would assume the two aren't compatible given the age of the gem and I'd probably investigate another gem (maybe [this one](https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2))

Comment: If you look thru the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/release-notes) you'll also find that linkedin is starting to deprecate at least some of the oauth 1.0 fields starting last year

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's so many things that this could actually be, but here's one thing you can try; you may not have requested the correct access when you configured your application. Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin):

> When requesting an authorization code in Step 2 of the OAuth 2.0 Guide, make sure to request the r_liteprofile and/or r_emailaddress scopes!

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) you can set these via the request, or thru the developer portal

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

  config.omniauth :linkedin,
    Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:linkedin][:client_id],
    Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:linkedin][:client_secret],
    scope: 'r_liteprofile'

I have added scope but that doesn't working.